# If statement will not run in do - while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement

Below is a demonstration of an issue I'm having.

The if statement in the do - while loop will not run. Even though the logic for the "while" is exactly the same and executes correctly. I've stepped through the issue with the debugger and the value of `testVar` is -1.00000000 and so on.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double testVar = 0.00;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter variable " << endl;
        cin >> testVar;
        if (testVar < 0.00) { "Yep!"; } **//Doesn't work.**

    } while (testVar < 0.00); **//Works**

    return 0;
}
```

```
The output of running this program looks like this:
Enter variable
-1
Enter variable
-1
Enter variable
-1
Enter variable
-1
```

Can someone please explain this behavior and offer a solution? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills because I should see "Yep!" when testVar = -1.00.

BTW I've developed in C# and Delphi. I'm currently taking C++ for a degree requirement.

Comment: What exactly does not work? `"Yep!";` does nothing.

Comment: I'd suggest cranking up your warnings.  gcc points to the exact problem with `-Wall`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Yep!";` isn't a statement that does anything.

You probably meant `std::cout << "Yep!\n";`.

I'd have expected your compiler to warn about this.

Comment: That was it. I may have become to reliant on my compiler telling me what's good or bad.  I need to get some sleep. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: It _will_ literally tell you about this. Did you turn off warnings?

Answer (score 4):

You just have a string literal there - you aren't printing it - you're missing the `cout` call:

```cpp
if (testVar < 0.00) { 
    cout << "Yep!" << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Yep, that will `do` it!